# missing ';' before '*' after instance declaration

Tags: c++, qt

I've encountered an error which I cannot seem to find a solution to anywhere else.

The error occurs when I'm trying to declare an instance of the "EncodeWindow" class.The compiler is giving errors C2143,C4430 and C2238. I am simply trying to give the "MainWindow" class an instance of "EncodeWindow".

File `mainWindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include "Image.h"
#include "encodewindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    /*Check whether a given file path is valid*/
    bool CheckFilePath(QString);

    /*Sets UI widgets*/
    void setOriginalImage_Label(const char*);
    void setEncodedImage_Label(const char*);
    void setDebug_TextBox(QString);        

    /*Saves all information about current encoding/decoding*/
    void saveFile();

private slots:    
    void on_Encode_Button_clicked();    
    void on_Reset_Button_clicked();
    void on_Save_Button_clicked();    
    void on_AddEncodeImage_Debug_Button_clicked();
    void on_AddImage_Button_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    EncodeWindow *CurrentEncodeWindow = new EncodeWindow;   //ERROR HERE!! C2143
    int fileNumber = 0;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

File `encodeWindow.h`:

```
#ifndef ENCODEWINDOW_H
#define ENCODEWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class EncodeWindow;
}

class EncodeWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit EncodeWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~EncodeWindow();

    /*Get filepaths from 'result' object (For access to filepaths without 'encode' Window)*/
    const char* getOriginalFilePath();
    const char* getEncodeFilePath();
    const char* getSaveFilePath();

    bool checkUI(const char*,const char*,const char*,bool*);
    bool CheckFilePath(const char*);
    std::string readInText(const char*);

private slots:
    void on_RedChannel_CheckBox_clicked(bool);
    void on_GreenChannel_CheckBox_clicked(bool);
    void on_BlueChannel_CheckBox_clicked(bool);
    void on_AlphaChannel_CheckBox_clicked(bool);
    void on_BitDepth_Slider_sliderMoved(int);
    void on_BitDepth_SpinBox_valueChanged(int);
    void on_Encode_Button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::EncodeWindow *ui;
    Encoded result;         //Enocoded object (child of Image class)
};

#endif // ENCODEWINDOW_H
```

Any help would be great. The code was done in Qt for an image steganography project.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a MWVE (minimal working verifiable example)? Does your code here contain the line with the error? It doesn't seems so because you say the error occurs when declaring an instance of the class, but the code here is only the class header.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the line with the error, but it would be easier if you broke your code up into blocks for the separate classes.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Does it support C++11?

Comment: Could you paste the complete error messages that you receive?

Comment: I think it is bad practice to initialize `EncodeWindow *CurrentEncodeWindow` by this way. Try to do it within constructor of `MainWindow()`?

Comment: My compiler does support C++11, I believe it is the Visual Studio C++ Compiler 14.0

Comment: My error messages were: C2143:syntax error: missing ';' before '*'                                   
                                           C4430:missing type specifier - int assumed. 
                                                       Note: C++ does not support default-int                    
                                           C2238:unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: If an answer has resolved your issue, you are encouraged to tick the green mark on the left of said answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have circular includes.  "mainwindow.h" includes "encodewindow.h" and "encodewindow.h" includes "mainwindow.h".  The include guards stop the cycle, but the class definitions for whichever header is included first won't be complete in the second include file, which will result in your errors.

In the snippet above, there's nothing that I see in `encodewindow.h` that uses anything in `mainwindow.h`, so just remove the include of mainwindow.h from encodewindow.h.

Comment: That was it , everything compiling now thanks. I wasn't aware of "circular includes" being a thing , however I will look into them for preventing this error again.